# Unsure of the role of these transistors while reverse engineering a keypad PCB

Tags: arduino, pcb, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer this PCB from a keypad to use it with an Arduino, but my transistor based knowledge is a bit lacking.

I have gotten this far with regards to the architecture of the board; JP1 Pins 1-8 are connected to the bottom pin on TR1 to 8. All the bottom pins of TR1 to 8 are common, and go to Pin A on JP2. The middle pin on the transistor is connected to some of the switches, and the other side of the switches goes to pins 9 to 15.

I have drawn out the scenario for SW13 (In the orange box).
My issue is I don't really know where to go from here.
[image: Image of PCB]

I can see maybe one of three scenarios;

- I apply a voltage to pins A and 4, and monitor the state of pin 10
- I apply a voltage to pins A and 10, and monitor the state of pin 4
- I apply a voltage to pins 4 and 10, and monitor the state of pin A

I know I will have to scan it like a matrix, but I am fairly confident in how that works once I have things figured out electronically.

Or, I have things completely wrong.

For the sake of completeness, JP3 goes to a daughter board with another button and two LEDs on, and TR 9-13 seem to be LED related.(D1,D2)
The writing on the transistors appears to be 24 0E (or 0E) but I can't seem to find anything for this on google to help me find what type of transistor and what the pinout might be.

Any help on the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: The board will need a power supply of some sort to operate. Probably 5V and connected to pins A and G but to figure it out which way round you'll need to know the polarity of D1 and D2. Then it will become fairly obvious whether the transistors are PNP or NPN and you can complete a schematic.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a schematic of what you think is going on with the RE ? Generally these things are repetitive in some way. Posting a schematic of say, one or two elements, of what you think is going on from the routing will help ... if you can't be bothered with a software package you can always draw it on paper ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are the '24' transistors are [DTC114ECA](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/digital/dtc114ecat116-e.pdf) prebiased transistors (10K + 10K).

'G1F' is probably BC847B NPN transistor. Unlike those of the prebiased persuasion, those will need base resistors or you'll burn out the transistor if you apply much voltage wrt ground. One of them obviously drives D2 LED and the others probably something similar off of JP3.

It's generally a good idea to put 1K in series with one side of whatever you're probing with.

That should be enough for you to figure out the schematic.